# React Router Link can't clone function

Tags: reactjs, constructor, hyperlink, router

I'm practicing my React and stumbled upon something I couldn't find the answer on the internet.
The context is: I'm making a page using the Random User API. On the main page the user navigating can browse through random people and add them to a list. Additionally, the user can click on a person's name and go to a page with more details about that person. I configured the route using React Router Dom and a Link attached to the thumbnail. So far so good. 
The problem is that when I decided to test some kind of constructors on this project, so when I fetch the person's info object from the API, I use a mini-constructor to add a few methods to it. Something like that:

```
function Person(person) {
  return {
    ...person,
    getFullName: () => `${person.name.first} ${person.name.last}`
  }
}

const data = await fetchPerson();
addPerson(Person(data));
```

So, on the main page there's no problem. I call getFullName() inside a `<p>` tag and it displays the name perfectly. But when I try to send this constructed Person object containing both the information and the method via `<Link>`'s state, I get an error saying that the function can't be cloned. Note: I tried using a class constructor as well. The error is the following:

```
DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': person => `${this.person.name.title} ${this.person.name.first} ${this.person.name.last}` could not be cloned.
```

I've tried declaring the function inside the Person functions and then referencing it inside the return and many other things but nothing seems to work. 
If I could have a light on the question, it'd be nice!
Thanks! :))
EDIT:
I tried declaring the function outside the "constructor" and it worked. But it isn't very clean. If any other suggestions/explanations surface I'd really like to now!

```
const getFullName = (person) => `${person.name.title} ${person.name.first} ${person.name.last}`;

export class Person {
  constructor(person) {
    this.person = person;
    this.getFullName = getFullName(person);
    this.test = 'IOEJASIEPASKEKASÇLEKÇASKEA'
  }
}
```

EDIT2: Tried with a function aswell, like the following, and worked. But I just can't understand the "cannot clone" error.

```
export function Person(person) {
  const getFullName = (person) => `${person.name.title} ${person.name.first} ${person.name.last}`;

  return {
    ...person,
    fullName: getFullName(person) ,
  }
}
```